# postgres function returns operator doesn't exist integer - timestamp

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic

Hi I have a function that when calling it to test returns the error in the question. i know it is to do with how i insert the variable into part of the query but i cannot work out why, i've tried changing the type castings around on it but no luck. any help would be appreciated

```
create or replace function ageing_balance_calc(start_date text, client_id text) returns void 
AS $BODY$ 
declare 
_absd date;
_client_id text;
req text; 
BEGIN
_absd:=(to_date(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'));
_client_id:= client_id;
with cte as 
(
Select * from crosstab('
select * from (
select absd, 
case when a.days_ago between 0 and 30 then ''0-30''
     when a.days_ago between 31 and 60 then ''31-60''
     when a.days_ago between 61 and 90 then ''61-90''
     when a.days_ago >90 then ''90+''
     else ''not due'' end as bucket, sum(a.item_amount)
from (select date_part(''day'',((due_date::timestamp) - ('||_absd||' ::text::timestamp)) )as days_ago, item_amount, '||_absd||'::text::date as absd  from fdw_test) a
group by bucket, absd)b order by 1,2') as   (absd date,
    bucket0_30 numeric,
    bucket31_60 numeric,
    bucket61_90 numeric,
    bucket90_plus numeric,
    not_due numeric)
)
update  ddva.kpi_calc_results
set 
absd = a.absd, 
bucket0_30 = a.bucket0_30,
bucket31_60 = a.bucket31_60, 
bucket61_90 = a.bucket61_90,
bucket90_plus = a.bucket90_plus, 
not_due = a.not_due from (
select absd, bucket0_30, bucket31_60, bucket61_90, bucket90_plus, not_due from cte) as a 
where ddva.kpi_calc_results.client_id = _client_id ; 
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

**update**
the date_part works if i remove it to its own query and then use $date to insert the date as a string that way. if i remove the to_date part at the start of the function i still get the same error as before. does '||x||' do anything to the data type?

Comment: You need to tell as update to your question what you want `select date_part(''day'',((due_date::timestamp) - ('||_absd||' ::text::timestamp))` to return?

Comment: this just needs to return how many days since the due date. so absd is the start date for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Well:

```
date_part(''day'',((due_date::timestamp)
```

is going to return an integer:

```
select date_part('day', now());
27
```

I'm guessing you want something more like:

```
select now()::date;  2021-07-27
```

**UPDATE**

This part:

`'''||_absd||'''::text::timestamp`

won't work either:

```
select '''||_absd||'''::text::timestamp;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "'||_absd||'"
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:[image]

the result query looks like this: `(2021-07-07::text::timestamp)` and results in error: iteger - timestamp.

You must add more quotes: `('''||_absd||'''::text::timestamp)`

Comment: That is not going to work as:`'''||_absd||'''::text::timestamp invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "'||_absd||'`

Comment: that will work, you forgot it is all inside the quotes as a first argument of crosstab()

Comment: Yeah, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

the below line:

```
(select date_part(''day'',((due_date::timestamp) - ('||_absd||' ::text::timestamp)) )as days_ago, item_amount, '||_absd||'::text::date as absd  from fdw_test)
```

was changed slightly to this:

```
(select date_part(''day'',((due_date::timestamp) - ('''||_absd||'''::timestamp)) )as days_ago, item_amount, '''||_absd||'''::date as absd  from fdw_test)
```

the function now works as expected

Comment: dealing with double or tripple quoting can be tricky, better way is to use dollar-qouting or FORMAT() function